# Can you make four attacks on the turn you cast Blade of Disaster?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

[Blade of Disaster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/blade-of-disaster) is a new spell which appears in [Icewind Dale: Rime of the Frostmaiden](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/idrotf) (p. 318) and also in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*.

According to the spell description *(emphasis mine)*:

> When you cast this spell, you can make up to **two melee spell attacks**
> with the blade

The description then goes on to say:

> As a **bonus action** on your turn, you can move the blade up to 30 feet
> to an unoccupied space you can see and then make up to **two melee spell
> attacks** with it again.

It seems that on the turn that you cast this spell, you can get up to 4 total attacks. Am I reading this  correctly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## It uses your bonus action to cast

Casting the spell uses your Bonus Action, so on the casting turn you only have the attack option available.

> You can take only one [bonus action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/combat#TheOrderofCombat) on your turn, so you must choose
> which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.

After that, it requires a bonus action to attack, leaving you with your action still available.

Answer (score 8):

### No, you can make two attacks

You can't take two bonus actions during your turn.

#### The spell has a casting time of a bonus action

The spell's casting time is a bonus action. This means that on the turn you cast it, you have used your bonus action and can't take the spell's bonus action. This is similar to *spiritual weapon* or *expeditious retreat*.

Answer (score 8):

### You already cast the spell using your bonus action.

Unless you can use more than one bonus action on your turn, or you can change the casting time of the spell to 1 action, you don't have another bonus action to use on your turn.

Answer (score 8):

#### *Blade of Disaster* has a casting time of 1 Bonus Action.

You only get 1 bonus action per turn, so once you've cast it, your bonus action is spent:

> You can take only one bonus action on your turn, so you must choose which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.